# Подключение к аканту discord?

Tags: python, discord

можно ли через python писать сообщения не через бота, а через зарегистрированный аккаунт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я знаю, это можно реализовать реализовать через Selenium. Довольно мощная библиотека, которая поможет сделать задуманное.

Comment: хорошо, попробую